# How to pattern match multivariate integral?

Tags: symbolic

I have been using a pattern

```
Integrate[c_ f_, it:{x_Symbol, __}] :> c Integrate[f, it] /; FreeQ[c, x]
```

which matches an integral and pulls out c if c has no dependence on x. Now if I have a multivariate integral then this won't match because the symbol `it` will have multiple lists like `{t2,0,t1},{t1,0,t}`. So is there a pattern that can find integrals with multiple variables like Integral[c f,{t2,0,t1},{t1,0,t}] and keep track of t1 and t2 so that I can pull out constants?

I tried

```
Integrate[c_ f_, it__:{x_Symbol, __}] :> c Integrate[f, it] /; FreeQ[c, x]
```

but it only matches the first integration variable and considers all other functions as independent of the rest of the integration variables.

Comment: Vs 13.3 does it automatically  Integrate[   3 p[y] q[x, z], {x, 0, 1}, {z, a, b}]   -> $$3 p(y) \left(\ \int _0^1\int _a^bq(x,z)\  dz \ dx \ \right)$$